# How to keep CSS Attributes specific to each page in a SPA build on Reactjs, when css is applied on body or html

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

For my login page I applied some css on the html,body since I am using React.js to build SPA.
When I navigate to homescreen after login the body is same so the CSS is applied everywhere.

How I can make it specific to only login page suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a specific class to its div container. example would be

```
.loginContainer{
  height:200px
}
```

and on your div container you call this on the className prop

```
<div className="loginContainer">Login container here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want CSS that is applied to a single component , take a look at [ShadowDom](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/shadow-dom) , One way to implement the ShadowDOM in react would be to use [react-shadow-root](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-shadow-root) , by using the ShadowDOM the CSS would not leak out of that component

Small Working Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-cookies-311hl)

Comment: Thanks Abdullah , will check this.